# How can I use externalized configuration files with the Gradle Tomcat plugin?

Tags: tomcat, configuration, classpath, gradle, gradle-tomcat-plugin

**Problem.** I have various environment-specific configuration files that I want to include on the classpath at runtime, but I don't want these to be part of the WAR itself. For example, I have a `log4j.xml` file for the dev environment with debugging turned on, and a properties file with lots of environment-specific credentials, endpoints and so forth.

I want these outside the WAR because I want to release the same WAR I test, rather than building separate environment-specific WARs. I could potentially include multiple environment-specific sets of configuration in the WAR (similar to the profile capability that both Maven and Spring provide), but I prefer not to.

Standalone Tomcat has the `shared.loader` feature (in `catalina.properties`), and Jetty has `extraClasspath`, but I don't know how to do this with the Gradle Tomcat plugin. Is there a way?

**Related posts.** The following posts are related, but they seem to involve copying the configuration files into locations that end up being pulled into the WAR file.

- [Gradle tomcat plugin and properties files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958679/gradle-tomcat-plugin-and-properties-files)
- [How do I add a .properties file into my WAR using gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683375/how-do-i-add-a-properties-file-into-my-war-using-gradle)

Answer (score 2):

Figured out a way to do this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:0.9.7"
        classpath files("/path/to/config/files")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the property `additionalRuntimeJars` for this. The name is a little bit off but the purpose is to add external JARs to Tomcat's classloader.

```
[tomcatRun, tomcatRunWar]*.additionalRuntimeJars << file("/path/to/config/files")
```

or

```
[tomcatRun, tomcatRunWar]*.additionalRuntimeJars = [file("/path/to/config/files")]
```

I am not sure if it is going to work but it's worth a try. If that doesn't work it would be great if you could open an issue for it on GitHub.

Comment: Sounds good Benjamin. I'll take a look at that. If this works, my thought is that this approach is superior to the answer I posted because it limits the scope of the extra classpathing to the Tomcat plugin. Note thought that I'm adding a directory of config files rather than adding JARs, so we'll see.

Comment: I looked at AbstractTomcatRunTask. The property name (additionalRuntimeJars) is correct, but it's not working using either of the suggested formulations. I'll create the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: For those who want to follow it: https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin/issues/41

Comment: With version 2.2.1 of the plugin the property has been renamed to `additionalRuntimeResources`. It works properly for me.