# configure catalina.properties gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, catalina

I have a Gradle Project, and I need add to the catalina.properties file:

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.jarsToSkip=bcprov*.jar
```

But I don't know where I can find this file in my gradle project.

Comment: can you provide more details about your project?  is it Spring Boot or standard Web App ?  are you deploying on embedded or existing Tomcat container ?

Comment: It's spring project, and I start my application using gradle tasks, I run `gradle tomcatStart`.

Comment: it seems you are using gradle-tomcat plugin: maybe  this answer can help you configure the properties file : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15069636/6899896

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if you are using *gradle-tomcat* plugin or not, but if you are: you could create a task that copy the `catalina.propeties`config file to the temporary Tomcat directory, and make the `tomcatRun` depends on this task. The `catalina.properties` file could be stored in your project resources , e.g.: in `src/main/conf`

```
ext{
    // path to catalina.properties in your project
    catalinaPropertiesPath = 'src/main/conf/catalina.properties'

    // path to temporary directory used by gradle-tomcat plugin
    tomcatTmpRunDir = "$buildDir/tmp/tomcatRun/conf"
}

// copy catalina.properties conf file
task copyCatalinaProperties(type: Copy){
    from( catalinaPropertiesPath)
    into(tomcatTmpRunDir)

}

// create task dependency
tomcatRun.dependsOn copyCatalinaProperties
```

( based on solution given here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15069636/6899896 )

Comment: I think this will help me, I'll try it. thanks. And my build.gradle: https://gist.github.com/I-am-Gabi/45201a70b855226be660b24c6ccc4f6b, Should I create the task dependency in my build.gradle?

Comment: Hey! Thank you! It's working. 
I made a little change: https://gist.github.com/I-am-Gabi/779ad0d6d7715d93e9c29e4499e54130